# Jquery AJAX POST get ID from response URI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This may be a really simple one but I have been searching the net for a few hours and can't find an answer!

I make a POST call to an API and it returns the ID in the URL (for example, the POST goes to /api/user and the response is /api/user/1).

I want to be able to retrieve that 1. Calling this.url in the .done function just returns http://localhost/api/user

Code is as follows:

```
ajaxHelper(url + '/api/user/', 'POST', user).done(function (item) {
//want to get the ID here
alert(this.url) //Returns the original URL without the ID (i.e. http://localhost/api/user
    }

function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    var headers = {};

    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        headers: headers,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Comment: You're using `this.url`; what does `item` contain? `item` is what contains the response from the server, no?

Comment: Yeah item does contain the response but I'm not sure how to get the headers out, just the returned JSON. I used this.url as I read it ran in the context of the .done method so it should have returned the ID (but didn't)

Answer (score 0):

If your response is `/api/user/1` and you wish to get data from there, you need to use the response that retuns. In your case, `item`:

```
.done(function (item) { ... })
```

`item` here will contain `/api/user/1`, and you can use this string to fetch whatever it is you need.

Comment: Returning item alone gives me [object Object] (as expected); returning item.url or item.Location gives me undefined. In Postman the location in the header comes back as http://localhost/api/user?id=24

Comment: If `item` is an object, try `console.log(item)` to find out what properties it actually has.

Comment: @user3129594 nnnnn wrote exactly what I was going to write :)

Comment: console.log(item) returns just the JSON response...doesn't actually return the URL or the headers from what I can see (using the javascript console in Chrome). The ID does not come back in the response, it only comes back in the returned URL.